# Detect type of json

Tags: ios, json, swift

I get different json object and I need to detect type of json messages (list of sellers, list of clients, product, order, ...).

Json type 1:

```
{"Sellers": [
        { "name":"A", "ID":5 },
        { "name":"B", "ID":4 }
    ]
}
```

Json type 2:

```
{"Clients": [
        { "name":"A", "SelectedProduct": "DDD" },
        { "name":"B", "SelectedProduct": "CCC" }
    ]
}
```

Json type 3:

```
{"ID": "78915"}
```

How can I detect type of json to parse it?

```
guard let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
                     let sellers = JSON["Sellers"] as? [[String: Any]],
                     let clients = JSON["Clients"] as? [[String: Any]],
                     let product = JSON["ID"] as? [String: Any],
else { return }

var type: JsonType
if(sellers != nil){
    type = ...
}
if(clients != nil){
    type = ...
}
```

What is the best way to detect type of json object? Can I detect it inside **guard let JSON** area?

Comment: What holds you from trying `guard let`?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. The `guard let` statement ensures that `sellers != nil` and `clients != nil` so both if statements will always happen.

Comment: But if you want to treat all these fields separately, then why did you treat them as a whole to being with? Just remove those from your guard and test them separately. Your question is not clear.

Comment: You should better add different variations of your JSON to better understand what solutions you have. And additionally specify if all the JSON examples are possible responses of the same API call.

Comment: I just added JSON examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base class JSONTYPE which inherits from NSOBJECT class.

Create 3 other classes, namely:
1. Seller -> 2 Properties (Name, ID)
2. Client -> 2 Properties (Name, SelectedProduct)
3. ID -> 1 Property (ID)

all of which inherit JSONTYPE class.

Then changing your code as follows:-

```
guard let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
                     let sellers = JSON["Sellers"] as? [Seller],
                     let clients = JSON["Clients"] as? [Client],
                     let product = JSON["ID"] as? [ID],
else { return }

var type: JSONTYPE
if(sellers != nil){
    type = ...
}
if(clients != nil){
    type = ...
}
```